# Open as PDF ajax returned document

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Here is the code. "core/bcsheet.php" returns PDF document but ajax shows as html code. How can I show PDF to user?

```
function ajaxPost() {
    form = $("#dbview");
    formData = form.serialize();   
    formUrl = "core/bcsheet.php";
    formMethod = form.attr('method');

    $.ajax({
        url: formUrl,
        type: formMethod,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (html) { 
            var win = window.open('', 'childWindow', 'location=yes, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');
            win.document.open();
            win.document.write(html);           
            // win.print();
            win.document.close();         
        //win.close(); 
        }
    });   
};
```

Comment: i dont think that you have much of a choice, you can point(`location.href=/path/to/pdf`) to the pdf document and the browser will open a download dialogue or else if the user has configured to open the pdf in browser it will show as pdf in whatever pdf viewer user has installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open the URL in a new window and add the script a pdf header while streaming the content via `print()`.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php